# Wpf TreeView get data item used to bind template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I am binding a TreeView with a custom template. I have a button in the template and when the user clicks it I need to find out the data item which was used to bind the specific template instance against.

So if I bind my TreeView to an IList I need to get the MyTreeItem that that provided the data for the specific template instance.

My code looks like this:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="268" Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" x:Name="TrViewCodeTree">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="roslynDemos:TrViewCodeTreeItem">
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Label Content="Node Type:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="70"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeType}" Margin="10,10,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    <Label Content="Node Position" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="80"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}" Margin="10,10,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    <Label Content="Node Length" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="75"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Length}" Margin="10,10,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    <Button x:Name="BtnSelect" Click="BtnSelect_OnClick"></Button>
                </WrapPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void BtnSelect_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var button = sender as Button;

   var dataitem = button.DataContext as [Your DataItem Class Here];

   dataitem.[DoStuffHere]();
}
```